# Webmatrix SQL CE Connection string

Tags: azure, webmatrix

I have never had the need to specify connection string in a webmatrix website. But now since Azure is giving the below error, people have recommended to declare the max database size.

THe error:
Error : The database file is larger than the configured maximum
database size. This setting takes effect on the first concurrent database
connection only. [ Required Max Database Size (in MB; 0 if unknown) = 257

Connections string I used:(but its not working...)
I get another error called: There is insufficient disk space to complete operation.

Can any one provide a sample connection string for webmatrix?
the database size should be in mb or gb?

I tried the below

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name = "SuhaniPittie.sdf" connectionString = "Data Source = SuhaniPittie.sdf; Max Database Size = 4096; Persist Security Info = False;" /> 
    </connectionStrings>
<system.web>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct solution: DataDirectory tag must be included.

can anyone comment on what is |DataDirectory| before the database name and are there any other ways of declaring the path... I tried app_data but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I configured mine.

```
    ...
    <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        <add invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" name="Microsoft® SQL Server® Compact 4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=MYTOKEN" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Then I just use `var dbData = Database.Open("MYDATABASENAME");` anywhere I need a database connection.

You'll need to plug in your values MYTOKEN and MYDATABASENAME.

Comment: I am using the same. But where do you add the databases size?

Comment: You can use the connection string you wrote, except for one modification:  Max Database Size is actually 4091.  Also, you probably need to provide a path for the file or it may not know where to look.